# jQuery.html() removes scripts and styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coding-style

Is there a way to use jQuery.html() and not loose the scripts and styles? or any other non-jQuery way?

I'm trying to output the full HTML of the page the user is on. Is this even possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you fully. If you do not want to lose your scripts and styles that seems like you only want to modify the body tag's content. Is that right? or you want to add new scripts and styles to the head too?  In that case you should register styles and scripts on a separate function. then append your body content. you can even set doctype and everything dynamically with JS. So it should be all good

Comment: What browser do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> jQuery.html() removes scripts and styles

That isn't my experience (see below). In practice, you have to be aware that what you get back by querying the DOM for HTML strings is always going to be the *interpreted* HTML, not the original, and there will be quirks (for instance, on IE all the HTML tag names are IN UPPER CASE). This is because jQuery's `html` function relies on the browser's `innerHTML` property, which varies slightly browser to browser. But the demo below includes both style and script tags on Chrome 4, IE7, and Firefox 3.6; I haven't tried others, but I would expect them to be okay.

If you want to get the content of externally-linked pages as well as the inline content, you will naturally have to parse the result and follow the `src` (on `script`s), `href` (on `link`s that have `rel` = "stylesheet"), etc...

Demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    $(document).ready(pageInit);

    function pageInit() {
        $('#btnGo').click(go);
    }

    function go() {
        alert($('html').html());
    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' id='btnGo' value='Go'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 scenarios here

1. you use jQuery.html(yourHTML) to overwrite the entire html of the page, so even the script tags were overwritten...
2. you use jQuery.html() to retrieve the entire document html. if this is the case you need tu ensure that the element on which .html() function is used, is the entire html... as T.J. Crowder suggested  `$('html').html()`