# Rails with Fancybox: ajax content is not displayed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fancybox

I'm having a problem when trying to display a popup window (fancybox) with a content rendered in the controller. Fancybox always displays message "The requested content cannot be loaded."

Here is the code I'm trying:

```
<%= link_to new_item_path(:format => 'js'), :remote => true, :class => 'new_item_popup fancybox.ajax', do %>
    <div class="bubble">
        Add a quick item
    </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#feedback_form").hide();

        $(".new_item_popup").fancybox({
            type        : 'ajax',
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });
    });
</script>
```

The interesting thing that I spotted with Firebug is that this code fires two new.js requests almost at the same time. I wonder if this is the reason for this problem.

Using Rails 3.0, with jQuery 1.7.1, latest rails.js and Fancybox 2.0.4.

Here is a content of application.html.erb, just in case:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.1.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.prettyPhoto' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.fancybox.pack' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'iphone-style-checkboxes' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'placeholder' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

By changing fancybox type parameter to 'iframe' I can get the popup visible. But then it displays the whole site in the popup, and not just the response.

Update: Turned out that this double ajax request is caused by this line in application.html.erb:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.1.min', 'rails', 'application' %>
```

By removing 'rails' from there the double call is also removed. Still, fancybox doesn't display the content, even though the reply is correct (checked via Firebug). Here is the reply content I'm trying to display via Fancybox:

```
<div id="create_new_item_window">
    <div class="margin_b"><h2>Create new item</h2></div>
    <div>
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/items" class="simple_form item" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_item" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="RaCmpqXV17piSDljz5VWl0y2INxHTrO5VREAczn+wY4=" /></div>
        <div id="new_item_basic_section">
            <div class="input string required"><label class="string required" for="item_title"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Title</label><input class="string required" id="item_title" maxlength="35" name="item[title]" required="required" size="30" type="text" /></div>
            <div class="input text optional"><label class="text optional" for="item_description"> Description</label><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="item_description" maxlength="450" name="item[description]" rows="20"></textarea></div>
            <div class="input boolean optional"><input name="item[public]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input checked="checked" class="boolean optional right" id="item_public" name="item[public]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label class="boolean optional" for="item_public"> My friends can see this item</label></div>
            <div class="input boolean optional"><input name="item[giveaway]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="boolean optional right" id="item_giveaway" name="item[giveaway]" type="checkbox" value="1" /><label class="boolean optional" for="item_giveaway"> Mark as giveaway</label></div>      
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="show_advanced_section_link" class="amaranth">Add even more details</a>
        <div id="new_item_advanced_section">
            <div class="input text optional"><label class="text optional" for="item_secure_details"> Secure details</label><textarea class="text optional" cols="40" id="item_secure_details" maxlength="450" name="item[secure_details]" rows="20"></textarea><span class="hint">Like serial number and other stuff that will stay private</span></div>
            <div class="input select optional"><label class="select optional" for="item_bookmark_id"> Bookmark</label><select class="select optional" id="item_bookmark_id" name="item[bookmark_id]"><option value="43" selected="selected">updated name</option>
<option value="44">Orange one</option>
<option value="45">Yellow one</option>
<option value="46">Green one</option>
<option value="47">Grey one</option></select><span class="hint">If this list looks empty, try giving some names to your bookmarks</span></div>
            <div class="input string optional"><label class="string optional" for="datepicker3"> Warranty until</label><input class="string optional" id="datepicker3" name="item[warranty_until]" size="30" type="text" /></div>
            <div class="image_attachment">
                <div class="attachment_text">
                    Add some photo <br><small>(JPG, PNG, max 500kb)</small>
                </div>
                <div class="attachment_button">
                    <input id="item_assets_attributes_0_photo" name="item[assets_attributes][0][photo]" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image_attachment">
                <div class="attachment_text">
                    Add a receipt <br><small>(JPG, PNG or PDF, max 500kb)</small>
                </div>
                <div class="attachment_button">
                    <input id="item_receipts_attributes_0_photo" name="item[receipts_attributes][0][photo]" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="hide_advanced_section_link" class="amaranth">Hide details</a>
        <div class="margin_r">
            <input class="button small_button white right" data-disable-with="Saving..." id="item_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Item" />
        </div>
</form>    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){  
    $("#show_advanced_section_link").click(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();  
        $("#show_advanced_section_link").hide();
        $("#hide_advanced_section_link").show();
        $("#new_item_advanced_section").slideDown();
    });
    $("#hide_advanced_section_link").click(function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();  
        $("#hide_advanced_section_link").hide();
        $("#new_item_advanced_section").slideUp();
        $("#show_advanced_section_link").show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_item_advanced_section").hide();
    $("#hide_advanced_section_link").hide();
});

$(function(){  
    $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
});
</script>
```

Update 2: Tried to initialize ajax call with jquery and pass the result to Fancybox as suggested in the comments. Doesn't work, Fancybox is not displayed at all:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fancybox').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax('/items/new.js', {
            success: function(result) {
                $.fancybox({ content: result ,type : 'inline', maxWidth : 800, maxHeight : 600, fitToView : false, width : '70%', height : '70%', autoSize : false, closeClick : false, openEffect : 'none', closeEffect : 'none' });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also tried like this (same result):

```
$(function(){
    $('.fancybox').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax('/items/new.js', {
            success: function(result) {
                $(result).fancybox();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The ajax request itself works fine, correct response received.

Comment: I'm not a rails crack but are you printing out a link with the css class **new_item_popup** and does it have a **href** attribute? Also, I see your response includes javascript and fancybox returns the ajax data using jQuery's **.html()** function which strips all javascript. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873353/jquery-html-removes-scripts-and-styles. Try and only load html with your ajax request.

Comment: Yes, the rendered link is like this: `<a href="/items/new.js" class="fancybox" data-remote="true">` I'll try loading plain html.

Comment: Rendering plain html without javascript also doesn't work. It actually feels that fancybox popup is displayed before the response is received from the server. Weird.

Comment: What you can try and do in that case is use jQuery ajax to get the html on on success you then call $.fancybox and set the "content" property with the html received from the ajax call. `$.fancybox({
            content: htmlreceivedbyajax,type        : 'inline',
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600,
            fitToView   : false,
            width       : '70%',
            height      : '70%',
            autoSize    : false,
            closeClick  : false,
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none'
        });`

Comment: Check the update - tried this, but no success.

Comment: Does fancybox open? Does it have a width and height?

Comment: Nope, it is not displayed at all now.

Comment: Let's keep the fancybox call simple. Try the following and if that doesn't work check your firebug console for any errors: `$.fancybox({
                    'content' : $(result),
                    'width' : 400,
                    'height' : 400
                });`

Comment: Tried, still the same- fancybox is not displayed at all. I've checked the firebug console for errors - nothing ("show javascript errors" option is enabled).

Comment: Fancybox works with pictures fine - just checked. But this ajax thing is seems to be more tricky.

Comment: I don't have many ideas left without seeing the code. I would try and use a simple string such as `<div>Test</div>`for 'content' and ignore the ajax call for now.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I'm not sure if the success: function() is called at all. Do you have any hint how to check this?

Comment: Use firebug's console.log or alert in the success function. If it doesn't get called, then there's an issue with the ajax request.